# Identifying the edited columns in the database

Tags: mysql, triggers

At the beginning the application have an `admins` and `employees` and `records`.

The records table has many columns than can be changed by any employee. However, this change can not be submitted. When the admin approve for an edit the record will show up again in the system.

I was trying to identify the column name and the value, and send it to another table using triggers on UPDATE.

So when the employee edits any record, the record will be disabled in the system. Also the admin will be able to know which values has been changed.

Is this possible in databases ?

```
Records Table
-------------------------------------------------------------------
record_id       record_name     record_serial       record_active
-------------------------------------------------------------------
    1            something          5151                 YES
```

When an update happens to the record_serial, such as from 5151 to 9844 I need to do this.

```
Records_changes
-------------------------------------------------------------------
change_id          record_col       record_old_val      record_new_val
-------------------------------------------------------------------
    1            record_serial          5151                 9844
```

At the same time

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
record_id       record_name     record_serial       record_active
-------------------------------------------------------------------
    1            something          9844                 NO
```

I can do it using my application, but if there is anyway to do it using the database it would be much nicer.

**I will use this to track the changes, and also create a history for the records old values.**

I am using `MySQL`

Comment: which database engine?

Comment: MySQL using the command line.

Comment: I'm thinking it would be easier to do this through the application.  But I'm curious as to whether anyone has any ideas for doing this through the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER tg_bu_records
BEFORE UPDATE ON records
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF NOT (OLD.record_serial <=> NEW.record_serial AND
          OLD.record_name <=> NEW.record_name) THEN
    SET NEW.record_active = 0;
  END IF;
END$$

CREATE TRIGGER tg_au_records
AFTER UPDATE ON records
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF NOT (OLD.record_serial <=> NEW.record_serial) THEN
    INSERT INTO records_changes (record_col, record_old_val, record_new_val)
    VALUES ('record_serial', OLD.record_serial, NEW.record_serial);
  END IF;
  IF NOT (OLD.record_name <=> NEW.record_name) THEN
    INSERT INTO records_changes (record_col, record_old_val, record_new_val)
    VALUES ('record_name', OLD.record_name, NEW.record_name);
  END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

**Note:** The trick is to change `record_active` flag in `BEFORE` trigger because it's the only event when you can change values of a row being updated/inserted in a table on which you defined that trigger. Now in `AFTER` trigger we record the changes that have been made.

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/19ced/1)** demo

Answer (score 0):

A good database pattern for this, if I understand your problem correctly, is to use versioned rows.  You add columns (or additional referenced tables) with meta data about when/who/what the edit was about.  When a record is edited, a new row is inserted. Previous versions are never modified or deleted.  Then it's up to your application logic to decide what to do with all of this.